# Remote SSH doesn't open file from terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

- Version of VS Code: Visual Studio Code 1.48.2
- What type of remote connection: SSH
- operating system: Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS (Xenial Xerus)
- remote operating system: Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS (Xenial Xerus)

I have a remote SSH connection set up between two machines, and it appears great. I can navigate the directory structure through the integrated terminal, open a remote workspace, and open files using CTRL+P to search for files in the work space. However, if I try to open a file from the remote system via the integrated terminal to my local instance of VSCode, nothing happens. `code file.txt` is a no-op, when instead I'd like to open the file in my current local window.

Comment: Any more info in `Remote-SSH: Show Log` ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately no. 
It just says
```"Resolved "ssh-remote+<machine>" to "IPaddress"
[Forwarding server <port#>] Got connection 1
[Forwarding server <port#>] Got connection 2
[Forwarding server <port#>] Got connection 3```
It's as if it thinks it is successfully opening it in a different window.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE Feb 2nd, 2024:
if `echo $VSCODE_IPC_HOOK_CLI` works on your machine (you're running under vscode-server) then I'd strongly recommend:

https://github.com/chvolkmann/code-connect

---

OLD ANSWER (still correct, but toil prone)

There are many potential reasons which could  prevent VSCode remote ssh integrated terminal from being able to open files via "code" command.

## Quick Fix:

To get vs-code to open remotely then try add this line in your .bashrc

```
alias code="${HOME}/.vscode-server/bin/$(ls -t1 ${HOME}/.vscode-server/bin | head -n 1)/bin/remote-cli/code"
```

Now you can open a file using `code -r filename.txt` to open a file in the integrated terminal.
The `-r` parameter re-uses the current window.

## More verbose Explanation:

From an integrated VS-Code terminal on the remote host:

```
# run this and verify the current user, show the .sock file and permissions are ok. 
echo $VSCODE_IPC_HOOK_CLI

# also check path and make sure you've got some entry to ~/.vscode-server should appear:
echo $PATH
```

I'm not perfectly sure the best/proper way for the .vscode-server path to get set by the integrated terminal.

I think it's related to the `terminal.defaultProfile` setting but I'm not 100% and may just be broken in my insider preview.

However I'm 100% sure if the ~/.vscode-server/bin/*/bin/remote-cli  doesn't appear in the path it won't work, you can try to add it:

```
export PATH=$PATH:"~/.vscode-server/bin/**/bin/remote-cli"
```

then the command `code -r filename.txt` will open the file in the integrated editor, however I think the alias solution in Quick Fix is easier/better.

Answer (score -1):

when I run `code -r filename`, I get error message

```
Unable to connect to VS Code server.
Error in request
```

it turns out I shouldn't use tmux, after I exit tmux, it works fine.

but I haven't figure out how to make this work in tmux