# files won't open from vscode integrated terminal while on remote-ssh connection

Tags: visual-studio-code, ubuntu-20.04, vscode-remote, xserver

I just can not open files from vscode integrated terminal while on remote-ssh connection
Local machine: **windows 10**
Remote machine: **Ubuntu 20.04**

here is a log from code trying to launch abc.txt

```
$ code abc.txt --verbose
No protocol specified
[9045:1002/183652.672418:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1402)] Unable to open X display.
The futex facility returned an unexpected error code.
/dev/fd/3: No such file or directory
Server response:
```

This is quite frustrating please help
Note: I've already tried `export DISPLAY=:0`

Comment: Have you figured anything out with this? I am running into the same problem "Unable to open X display". I never had to have an X display before.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63760388/remote-ssh-doesnt-open-file-from-terminal

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are using the [remote development](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview) feature of vscode. Then you can use the integrated [explorer](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_explorer) to open files.

Comment: but I also want to be able to open them from integrated terminal. Opening files from integrated explorer requires the root folder of the file to be open in vscode.